# como hacer que el texto de la tabla aparezca abajo aun estando dentro de <table>

Tags: table

Es una reseta, tengo que poner las instrucciones debajo de la tabla, pero tambien deben estar dentro de la , pero cuando lo hago me aparece arriba de la tabla. alguna ayuda? gracias.

Comment: Hola! podrías añadir el código que tienes actualmente? También intenta que la pregunta sea lo mas clara posible.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].